# Sort a column in Worksheet using Python

Tags: python, xlsxwriter, worksheet

In the below program i have created a workbook which contains a worksheet named sort 
where i have placed words in one column and Numbers in another column
Now i have successfully outputed the .xlsxv file
But i need the numbers should be sorted from DESCENDING TO ASCENDING ORDER.
I don't know how to place the code for that.

```
Code
=====

import csv
import xlsxwriter
import re
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('wordsandnumbers.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('sort')
with open('sort.csv') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   alist = list(reader)


worksheet.write(2,0,'words')
worksheet.write(2,1,'Numbers')

newlist = []
for values in alist:
          convstr = str(values)
          convstr = convstr.split(",")
          newlist.extend(convstr)

a=3
for i in range(3,10):
    newlist[a] = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]','',newlist[a])
    worksheet.write(i,0,newlist[a].strip('['))
    a=a+1
    newlist[a] = re.sub('[^0-9]','',newlist[a])
    int(newlist[a])
    worksheet.write(i,1,newlist[a])
    a=a+1


workbook.close()
```

The Output i'm getting in .xlsx sheet is :

[image]

Needed output:

(The corresponding words which is in the same row of number should also be sorted)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend loading your original csv as a dataframe and then sorting it by a particular column.  I've provided a fully reproducible example below that illustrates this.

I make my own version of sort.csv for demonstration purposes, then read it in as a dataframe using `pandas.read_csv`, and then sort using `pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`.

```
import pandas as pd

sort = open('sort.csv', 'w+')
sort.write('May, 5227\n')
sort.write('June, 417\n')
sort.write('Jan, 4\n')
sort.write('Feb, 424\n')
sort.write('Dec, 36\n')
sort.write('Mar, 4981\n')
sort.write('Apr, 3460\n')
sort.close()

df = pd.read_csv('sort.csv', names = ['words', 'Numbers'])

df = df.sort_values(['Numbers'], ascending=[False])

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('wordsandnumbers.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False, startrow=2)
writer.save()
```

Outputted sort.csv:

[image: Outputted sort.csv]

Outputted wordsandnumbers.xlsx:

[image: Outputted wordsandnumbers.xlsx]

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the data into the array its straightforward to sort it and maintain order. You can just use the built in sort but give it a key which is the value you want the list sorted based on. See [this](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/lambdas.html).

```
import csv
import xlsxwriter
import re
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('wordsandnumbers.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('sort')
with open('./sort.csv') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   alist = list(reader)


worksheet.write(2,0,'words')
worksheet.write(2,1,'Numbers')

#Here convert the number to an integer
newerlist = [[x[0], int(x[1])] for x in alist[1:]]
print(newerlist)
#key is the function applied to the arguments to get the answer and lambda
#is just a 1 line way to write a function f(x) which returns x[1] (the number in the rows) 
newerlist.sort(key = lambda x : x[1], reverse = True)

a=3
for i in range(3,9):
    for j in range(0,2):
        worksheet.write(i,j,str(newerlist[i-a][j]))


workbook.close()
```